# $L:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $L(x,y)=(x,-y)$ which of the following is true?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

$L:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $L(x,y)=(x,-y)$ which of the following is true?

1. differentiable everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^2$
2. differentiable on $(0,0)$ only
3. $DL(0,0)=L$
4. $ DL(x,y)=L$ for all $(x,y)$

I have calculated that derivative matrix is $DL=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$

so $DL(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}\times (x,y)^T=(x,-y)$ so $DL=L$ so $4$ is true right? and hence also $1$ is true.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. $L$ is a linear map so its derivative is itself.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong Thank you very much

Comment: Can you explain me the question why the derivative is obtained by the product of derivative matrix and transpose of $L(x,y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This CW answer intends to remove the question from the unanswered queue.*

---

As Christopher A. Wong already noted you have correctly calculated that 4 is true. And hence also 1 is true. Note that 4 being true also implies 3 being true.